# .htaccess: if statement to disable password protection if get parameter is set

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I need password protection enabled, except when a certain get parameter is set.

Current working code (enables protection in folder `secure`):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^(?:.+\.)*sub\.domain\.com$/">
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/secure/" SECURE
</If>
Require valid-user
Order      allow,deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=SECURE
```

When calling e.g. `https://sub.domain.com/secure/?access_token=12345`, password protection should not be enabled, **something like this**:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^(?:.+\.)*sub\.domain\.com$/">
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} != /^access_token$/">
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/secure/" SECURE
    </If>
</If>
```

But `"%{QUERY_STRING} != /^access_token$/"` gives me an internal server error.

Comment: You should check your server's error log for the details of the "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <If "%{QUERY_STRING} != /^access_token$/">
> ```

The Internal Server Error might be caused by the use of the `!=` (not-equal) operator as used with *strings* instead of the `!~` (not-match) operator to compare against the regex. For example, it should read:

```
 <If "%{QUERY_STRING} !~ /^access_token$/">
```

Although this is naturally successful when the `QUERY_STRING` is not exactly `access_token`. The access token *value* is omitted. So, maybe you also need `/^access_token=12345$/`.